# Can't make a filterable table. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a filterable table like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_filters_table&stacked=h) one. That is, to render the existing table filterable. I copied the code on the *w3schools* website, but it doesn't work. I type text, but nothing gets filtered

```html
<div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active table-responsive">
                        <input class="form-control" id="my-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">

                        <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                            <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                        <!-- headings -->
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="table-body">
                        <!-- table body and the rest -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my-search-input").on("keyup", function() {
            let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#table-body tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- JS imports -->
</body>
```

[image]

Initially, I had these JS imports

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then I tried replacing them with the imports they had on *w3* (should I have clean-installed after that?)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried moving the script around

**What's the problem and how do I make my search field work and filter the rows of my table as intended?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my JQuery import has to be before my `<script>` that utilizes JQuery. If I place the `<script>` after the JQuery import, it works fine. Rookie mistake!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Users Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
            <input class="form-control my-2" id="my-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                      <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="table-body">
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-search-input").on("keyup", function () {
            let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#table-body tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, the only script needed is jQuery (full or slim).

We have to add the jQuery library to our webpages inside the head tag at the top, before any other libraries since there are many libraries depends on it like bootstrap and popper.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my-search-input").on("keyup", function() {
            let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#table-body tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active table-responsive">
<input class="form-control" id="my-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<table class="table table-hover text-center">
    <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! But what was my mistake, exactly? Was it the fact that my `<script>` elements weren't in the `<head>`? But Bootstrap itself says `<script>` should be before the closing `<body>` tag: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Only load jQuery itself in the head, the other js libraries should be before the closing `<body>`, In some cases if jQuery is loaded at the `<body>` you get a "$ is not defined" error.

Comment: For some reason, moving JQuery to the head, indeed, helped _(why?? also, why did Bootstrap say to put `<script>`s at the end of the `<body>`?? it's soo confusing...)_. Thank you very much 

Comment: Putting jquery in the <head> ensures it's ready before any of your content. Including your javascript code

Comment: Look, I still don't understand. Even Codecademy says, "When you add the jQuery library to your project in the next exercise, you will do so on the line before the </body> tag. Because HTML files load from top to bottom, adding the jQuery library at the bottom of your project will ensure that it will not affect the HTML (structure) and CSS (style) load times" (https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-jquery/lessons/jquery-setup/exercises/jquery-library). Why is it different in my project?

Comment: I just realized that my JQuery doesn't have to be in the head, but it _has_ to be before my `<script>` that utilizes JQuery. If I take JQuery back to the <body> and place the `<script>` after the import, it works too